Serialize string to a json value string
I have a scenario where I need to update a field value within an existing serialized JSON string before deserializing it. Specifically, I have the following:

Original Serialized JSON String:
"{\"name\":\"ValueToReplace\"}
String to Insert:
"user\name"

I want to replace "ValueToReplace" in the JSON string with "user\\\\name" so that it seamlessly integrates into the JSON structure. However, when I attempt to serialize "user\\name" using JsonConvert.SerializeObject, the output includes additional escaping and quotes ("\"user\\\\name\"").
Desired Output: After replacing "ValueToReplace" with "user\\\\name", the updated serialized JSON string should be:
"{\"name\":\"user\\\\name\"}".
How can I achieve this properly so that "user\\\\name" behaves correctly within the original JSON structure? This way, upon deserialization, the field "name" retrieves the value "user\\name".
Note: I don't want to do it for this specific format, but that it'll work for any string with any format.
Thank you for your assistance!


To achieve the desired output, we'll need to manually replace the target value within the JSON string and then deserialize it. Here's a breakdown of the steps:

Replace the Value
Use string.Replace to replace the target value with the desired replacement, including the necessary backslashes.
Deserialize the Updated JSON
Use "JsonConvert.DeserializeObject" to convert the updated JSON string into a dynamic object


What are the necessary backslashes? I want it to act exactly like a Json value. How can I know what are all the required replacements that JsonConvert.SerializeObject does?
